# Moving gameobjects with offset with finger

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, 2d-games

im currently developing a 2d mobile game with unity and i am still a begginner, so i need help with this one feature for my game.

What im trying to make is a dude on a pogo stick jumping automatically as soon as he hits the ground and the player has to move the pogo stick left and right to controll the player. For example if the pogo stick is moved to the left the player will jump to thr right because he is tilted to the left.

So i made the player jump automatically but i cant figure out how to move the pogo stick. I have seen tutorials for the player moving with your finger or moving the player with offset, but i dont want to move the whole player, only the bottom of the pogo stick.Also i need something like limits where i cant tilt the player more than like 60 degrees or something.

I am trying to do this for such a long time, i searched for tutorials, asked questions but i never found anything useful that could solve my problem, so please guys share any information and i will try to make the best out of it.

Also here is the code i use for the jumping player, if its any useful:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask platformLayerMask;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider2D; 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody2D= transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boxCollider2D= transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded())
        {
            float jumpVelocity = 7f;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity;

        }
        
    }

    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D raycastHit2d = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider2D.bounds.center, boxCollider2D.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, 0.05f, platformLayerMask);
        return raycastHit2d.collider != null;
    }
}
```

Thank you!